# How to cancel Toast created in a different method on android?

Tags: android, toast

I have the following code:

```
private Toast movieRecordToast;

    private void displayNextMovie() {
        if (movieRecordToast != null) movieRecordToast.cancel(); // cancel previous Toast (if user changes movies too often)
        movieRecordToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        movieRecordToast.show();

    private void displayPrevMovie() {
        if (movieRecordToast != null) movieRecordToast.cancel();
        movieRecordToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Prev", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        movieRecordToast.show();
```

But if `displayNextMovie` is called quickly several times and then `displayPrevMovie` is called, "Next" Toast is still shown and only after that "Prev" is displayed.
Looks like cancellation doesn't work properly.

Comment: Upd. looking at other questions about the same - looks like android just don't cancel Toast too fast...

Comment: As an aside, why don't you have a single function `private void displayMovieToast(String s)` which takes either "Prev" or "Next" as an argument?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of creating a new `Toast` object each time you want a new text displayed you can easily hold on to only one `Toast` object and cancel the current `Toast` whenever you want. Before the next `Toast` is being displayed you can change text with `Toast.setText()` function.

Sample code:

```
private Toast mToastText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the object once.
    mToastText = Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

private void displayText(final String message) {
    mToastText.cancel();
    mToastText.setText(message); 
    mToastText.show();
}
```

Comment: I like your solution but now my toasts are just not appearing. Any ideas? :?

Comment: In my case, the mToastText.cancel() made that the toast was not displayed. Without it, works perfectly. :)

Comment: Works perfectly for me, thanks. This was bugging me for ages!

Comment: @Wroclai Please update your answer to un-include a call to mToastText.cancel() as it screws stuff up in later versions of android. Making mToastText static also wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: I was also able to get this to work without the cancel call, however when going from a wide toast to a smaller toast, the toast kind of jumps in a glitchy way.

Comment: strangely enough, I am getting "void cannot be converted to android.widget.Toast" when I do something like private Toast mytoast; and set mytoast = Toast.makeText(RetrieveInfoActivity.this, "Setup Complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways you can achieve displaying the next/prev info to the user. I would ditch the toasts altogether and **update the text of a TextView** with the name of next/prev movie. That would eliminate your problem and also IMHO makes for better UI.

However, if your design requirements do ask for toast notifications, try:

```
    private Toast nextMovieRecordToast;
private Toast prevMovieRecordToast;


private void displayNextMovie() {
    if (prevMovieRecordToast != null) prevMovieRecordToast.cancel(); // cancel previous Toast (if user changes movies too often)
    nextMovieRecordToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    nextMovieRecordToast.show();}

private void displayPrevMovie() {
    if (nextMovieRecordToast != null) nextMovieRecordToast.cancel();
    prevMovieRecordToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Prev", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    prevMovieRecordToast.show();    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @OceanBlue. However, I think you approach will not work if displayNextMovie is called multiple times - there will be a queue of "Next" messages

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on what you want. The user will see "Prev" toast. The "Next" toasts behind it will time out themselves. So if you run this code, the effect should be what you desire. However... you're sure you HAVE to use toasts to for this?

Answer (score 0):

The wroclai's solution is excellent! However it screws the Toast when going form long message toast to short one and vice versa.
To fix this instead of using previous object recreate it. So instead of this line:
    `mToastText.setText(message);`
write this one: `myToast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`
The animations also looks better :)