# Cancelling an already open toast in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, toast

I'm currently starting to develop Android applications and I've been following up a [this tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) on how to use and improve the Google maps application.

I've managed to show up on screen the map, on touch I get the address of a location (via Reverse Geocoding) with the showing of a `Toast`. But here is my problem - when you click a number of consecutive times over the map you will get all the `toasts` one after other and each of them will take his time (in my case - `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`) to disappear. I want to make the application automatically close the older toast and show a new toast with the new address clicked.

In other resources I found I should use the `toast.cancel()` method for this purpose, but I experience trouble using it - I have already overrided the `onTouchEvent` - how can I detect there is a new touch over the map while the `toast` is showing? 
Or maybe you would suggest me a better way of hiding the already open `toast`?

I've tried to make my `Toast` address a global one, but it wasn't working also.

Here is my code for the application:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {   
    //---when user lifts his finger---
    if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
        GeoPoint p2 = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(p2.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                    p2.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
            String add = " ";
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                    add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
            Toast address;
            address = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            address.show();                     
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How is toast.cancel() not working? Is it being called?

Comment: Also, I would recommend using `ACTION_UP == event.getAction()` instead of `event.getAction() == 1`. It is just good style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel Toast created in a different method on android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503682/how-to-cancel-toast-created-in-a-different-method-on-android)

Comment: Thanks, @Pompe de velo - this is what I was searching for! 
Tack

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't show where you have `Toast address` as a global, but you are creating a new, local Toast object each time you click with:

```
Toast address;
address = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
address.show();
```

Which will override the global object you are creating. I'd recommend having `address` as a `private static` object in your class to ensure that address will always be the same object no matter how many times you click so that you are always cancelling the `Toast` that you last showed (since there is only ever one), and remove the local declaration:

```
private static Toast address;
```

...

```
if (address != null)
    address.cancel();

address = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
address.show();
```

Comment: I've moved the 
`private static Toast address;`
declaration as a global one.

If now I use the address.cancel() method it will just cancel my toast and nothing will show - how to call the cancelling of a toast only when there is a new touch on the screen?

Comment: Just call `address.cancel()` in your onTouchEvent before you show the new toast - this will cancel an existing toast if there is one (either showing or waiting to be shown) I've updated my suggestion to include this.

Comment: I tried with the 
`address = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),add, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
address.cancel();
address.show();`

but I get the same result - the toast changes only after it's lifetime ends.

Comment: I found the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503682/how-to-cancel-toast-created-in-a-different-method-on-android
`private Toast mToastText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the object once.
    mToastText = Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

private void displayText(final String message) {
    mToastText.cancel();
    mToastText.setText(message); 
    mToastText.show();
}`
Maybe this was your original idea - thanks!

Comment: Your first attempt was cancelling the pending toast before you displayed it, the second one you found is exactly the kind of thing I was going for - glad you solved your problem.

Comment: Does not work! Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503682/how-to-cancel-toast-created-in-a-different-method-on-android

Answer (score 1):

You need to get instance when create Toast by call make().After that before you show new toast, you should cancel old Toast.GoodLuck!

Comment: Is the `Toast.makeText` working the same way as `make()` ?
Here I have a question - on the beginning of my OnTouchEvent method I can have a check for an already open toast - if there is an open one - cancel it and procede forward with the opening of a new one. But is there a build-in method for check for the existance of an open toast?

Comment: RivieraKid mention the solution which is same with my way.

Comment: I didn't got yours previously, now I know how it's done I quite undestand it - thanks.