# Android Toast Accumulation Testing

Tags: android, testing, toast, functional-testing, robotium

Like many others, i've been trying to solve the problem of toast accumulation.

- [How to prevent Multiple Toast Overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922516/how-to-prevent-multiple-toast-overlaps)
- [toast issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295765/toast-issue-in-android)
- [Cancelling an already open toast in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744147/cancelling-an-already-open-toast-in-android)
- [Best way to avoid Toast accumulation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676471/best-way-to-avoid-toast-accumulation-in-android)

I finally decided to keep track of the current displayed toast and cancel it when another arrives (there's some more logic involved), but i could have use only one toast and change it message. What i want to know is this... Is there a way to TEST this behaviour? Im currently using Robotium and tried different things, but unfortunately the methods to check for toasts (`solo.waitForText` and `solo.searchForText`) aren't helping me as i can't make something like

```
assertTrue(solo.waitForText(text));
//maybe even some sleep here
assertFalse(solo.searchText(text);
```

Has anyone done something like this? Is there a way to test this using Robotium? using somethig else?

Comment: what do you mean aren't helping? does the test fail? what happens?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry, test fails at second assert, as it matches the text from the toast, when you would want the toast gone. Does it make sense?

Comment: Wait until the toast has disappeared before doing the second assert. Something like: while(solo.waitForText("my toast"); and then assertFalse(..)

Comment: Actually while(solo.searchText("my toast"); would be better to use in this case.

Comment: Mmm, interesting... have you tried that approach? I mean in working piece of code. I wonder whether if that `while` might catch many accumulated toast if they were to pop up... Because that's what we are testing against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a robotium condition to wait for the text to disappear. Here's a method I use for that.

```
private void waitForTextToDisappear(final String text, int wait) {
    Condition textNotFound = new Condition() {

        @Override
        public boolean isSatisfied() {
            return !solo.searchText(text);
        }
    };
    assertTrue("Text gone: " + text, solo.waitForCondition(textNotFound, wait));
}
```