# Android bugs on device. What should I do to fix them?

Tags: java, android

In my application I noticed these three things:

-The back button is enabled when going from one activity to another enabling the user to click on back to the original activity. The problem is I don't want the user to click on Back at a certain point in my application. I don't want to disable the back button completely in my application, only when one intent is called. How can I do that?

-I noticed something strange... when a toast notification pops up in my application all is well until I exit my application. When I exit my application, some of the toast notifications are residual and are popping outside of my application. Is there a reason for that? Did I miss something in the activity lifecycle to handle the cancellation of toasts at a certain point?

Lastly, this one is rather tough to solve. How do I lock my screen so that when the user rotates the device, that the activity doesn't not get called again and the asynctask can still resume without starting over again?

Thanks a lot for your time. Just curious why these things happen and what should I look into?

Here's my code:

```
//Main Activity.java

package com.example.Patient_Device;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //fields
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private Context context;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_setup);
        //Set the context
        context = this;

        //Initialize the start setup button and add an onClick event listener to the button
        final Button start_setup_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_setup_button);
        start_setup_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Executes the AsyncTask
                new RetrieveInfoTask().execute();

                //Instantiates the intent to launch a new activity
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RetrieveInfoActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
    }

    public class RetrieveInfoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        //Called on the UI thread to execute progress bar
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressBar.setCancelable(false);
            progressBar.setMessage(MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.retrieve_info));
            progressBar.show();
        }

        //Methods that retrieves information from the user device. This is performed in the Background thread
        private void retrieveInfo() {

            try {

                //Reading the drawable resource line by line
                String str="";
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                InputStream is = MainActivity.this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.user_info);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                if (is!=null) {
                    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buf.append(str + "\n" );
                    }
                }
                is.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        //doInBackground calls retrieveInfo() to perform action in Background
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            retrieveInfo();
            return null;
        }

        //When the background task is done, dismiss the progress bar
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (progressBar!=null) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }


    }
}

//RetrieveInfoActivity.java

package com.example.Patient_Device;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RetrieveInfoActivity extends Activity {

    private static String TAG = "RetrieveInfoActivity";
    private Context context;
    String fileLastSync = "09-18-2014 03:47 PM";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            context = this;

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.retrieve_info);

            //Once the new activity is launched, the setup is complete
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Setup Complete!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Gets the 'last synced' string and sets to datetime of the last sync
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            String syncString = String.format(resources.getString(R.string.last_sync), fileLastSync);

            //Dynamically sets the datetime of the last sync string
            TextView lastSyncTextView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_sync) );
            lastSyncTextView.setText(syncString);

            //calls registerReceiver to receive the broadcast for the state of battery
            this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,new
                    IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));


   }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()  {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

            //Battery level
            int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);

            //Dynamically sets the value of the battery level
            TextView batteryTextView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.battery) );
            batteryTextView.setText("Battery Level: " + String.valueOf(level)+ "%");

            //If the battery level drops below 25%, then announce the battery is low
            //TODO: Add 25 to constants file.
            if(level < 25) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Low Battery!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
            //Plugged in Status
            int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

            //Battery Status
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

            //If the device is charging or contains a full status, it's charging
            boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                    status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

            //If the device isCharging and plugged in, then show that the battery is charging
            if(isCharging && plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Charging.." + String.valueOf(level)+ "%",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unplugged!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        try {
            super.onDestroy();
            unregisterReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(RetrieveInfoctivity.TAG, getClass() + " Releasing receivers-" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

//StartSetupActivity.java


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class StartSetupActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
}

//FragmentsActivity.java


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentsActivity extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with this, [Debugging with Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-debug.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all whenever you want to disable back press just override onBackPressed() method and remove super. like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Second you'r using application context to show toast. use activity context.

```
Toast.makeText(this or YourActivity.this, "Setup Complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Third just add this attribute into your manifest class. This will avoid recrating your activity when orientation change

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: Something interesting to note is when I add "android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>", the toasts still get called again when the device is rotated.

Comment: are you using activity context to show toast like i described here?

Comment: Actually when I change the toast to use activity context, it says, it cannot resolve Toast.makeText.

Comment: share the log details please

Comment: java: no suitable method found for makeText(java.lang.Class<com.example.Device.RetrieveInfoActivity>,java.lang.String,int)
    method android.widget.Toast.makeText(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<com.example.Device.RetrieveInfoActivity> cannot be converted to android.content.Context)
    method android.widget.Toast.makeText(android.content.Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<com.example.Device.RetrieveInfoActivity> cannot be converted to android.content.Context)

Comment: Toast.makeText(RetrieveInfoActivity.this, "Setup Complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); you'r doing this right?

Comment: yes exactly. I am doing that.

Comment: oh I tried.. Activity.this and it seems to work

Comment: Btw, the toasts will reset back when the view is rotated and still appear outside of the application for a sec or two when I close the app or go to a screen outside my application.

Comment: i don't think your toast is resetting when orientation change it's just keep showing until dismis. Just decrease your toast length. Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.

Comment: Just curious, do I need to manually dismiss the toast in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer these in order:

**Back Button**

You can override onBackPressed in your Activity and determine if you want to consume it or let Android process it.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Set this how you want based on your app logic
    boolean disallowBackPressed = false; 

    if (!disallowBackPressed)
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Toasts**

Toasts are enqueued with the Notification Manager.  If you show multiple Toasts in a row, they get queued up and shown one at a time until the queue is empty.

**Locking Orientation For Activity**

Use android:screenOrientation="landscape" or android:screenOrientation="portrait" on your activity element in your manifest to lock the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that these questions should be asked separately, because the answer in detail to every item of your question is too long, but I hope this helps:

> -The back button is enabled when going from one activity to another enabling the user to click on back to the original activity. The
>   problem is I don't want the user to click on Back at a certain point
>   in my application. I don't want to disable the back button completely
>   in my application, only when one intent is called. How can I do that?

You can override the onBackPressed on the activities you don't want the user to go back.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        //Leave it blank so it doesn't do anything
}
```

> -I noticed something strange... when a toast notification pops up in my application all is well until I exit my application. When I exit my
>   application, some of the toast notifications are residual and are
>   popping outside of my application. Is there a reason for that? Did I
>   miss something in the activity lifecycle to handle the cancellation of
>   toasts at a certain point?

I think that the reason behind that is that toast go into a que, and are showed in order, even if the app is no longer visible.

> Lastly, this one is rather tough to solve. How do I lock my screen so
>   that when the user rotates the device, that the activity doesn't not
>   get called again and the asynctask can still resume without starting
>   over again?

For this, you can use the following code in your manifest

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>`

However this is NOT recommended by google, I suggest you read the following link to get a little more information on how to handle orientation changes:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Something interesting to note is when I add "android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>", the toasts still get called again when the device is rotated. I wonder why?

Comment: Are you sure they are not showing because they were previously added in the queue?

Comment: Every time you do a show() of a toast, they go into a queue.
Android will show the toast in order, even if the app is not running, it is a normal android behaviour

Comment: Can I kill the toast when the user navigates to something outside outside of my app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503682/how-to-cancel-toast-created-in-a-different-method-on-android

Comment: Thanks for that link but strangely enough, I am getting "void cannot be converted to android.widget.Toast" when I do something like private Toast mytoast; and set mytoast = Toast.makeText(RetrieveInfoActivity.this, "Setup Complete!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: mytoast = Toast.makeText(RetrieveInfoActivity.this, "Setup Complete!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); mytoast.show();